# Structure of pluginable application

Tags: php

I would like to write application in PHP and make it pluginable. So I want to have a core with basics functions and plugins, which I will add when I need. (When I write plugin I mean code in different file,  which is extending functionality)

How to make structure of such app? Would some MVC Framework (Zend, Nette) help? How can I do auto-loading into menu and/or into target pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 and Symfony 2 provides Dependency Injection and Services which are suitable for your needs.

A service is what you call a plugin, and you can inject that service/plugin to the part of the application that you need.